# How do I get the X-Axis value of clicked data point LiveCharts

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am trying to get the X-Axis label of a `CartesianChart` after clicking a data point.
I need the label as it contains a `DateTime` that I can use to load in more data and load the next chart. I cannot find anything similar. Can someone point me in the right directions or provide some code so I can continue with my work ?

Here is the chart itself:

```xml
            <lvc:CartesianChart DataClickCommand="{Binding DrillDownCommand}" Series="{Binding SeriesCollectionDatum}" LegendLocation="None" Margin="10,10,10,0" Background="#c0c1bf" Height="222" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Datum" Labels="{Binding LabelsDatum}" LabelsRotation="20" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
                        <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                            <lvc:Separator StrokeThickness="0" Step="1"/>
                        </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    </lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Broj" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
                        <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                            <lvc:Separator StrokeThickness="1" Step="10"/>
                        </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    </lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

The `DrillDownCommand` is bound in my `ViewModel` and it takes a `ChartPoint` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting`. Surprisingly easy to use and works like a charm for, in my case, smaller data sets.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<livechart:CartesianChart x:Name="dothi"
                          Height="420"
                          Width="950"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          Series="{Binding SrC}"
                          FontSize="15"
                          FontWeight="Medium"
                          LegendLocation="Bottom"
                          DataClick="dothi_DataClick">

                <livechart:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <livechart:Axis x:Name="TrucHoanhX" Labels="{Binding Labels}" FontSize="9.25" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" PreviewRangeChanged="TrucHoanhX_PreviewRangeChanged">
                        <livechart:Axis.Separator>
                            <livechart:Separator Step="1" />
                        </livechart:Axis.Separator>
                    </livechart:Axis>
                </livechart:CartesianChart.AxisX>

                <livechart:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                    <livechart:Axis Title="Doanh Thu" Labels="{Binding Values}" FontSize="15.5" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"></livechart:Axis>
                </livechart:CartesianChart.AxisY>

</livechart:CartesianChart>
```

```
private void dothi_DataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartPoint)
{
       string getDate = TrucHoanhX.Labels[(int)chartPoint.X];
       MessageBox.Show(getDate);       
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq2r0.png)

Comment: Please provide code samples as text formatted as code

Comment: @moken Here you go, sir :D